# How to change level as Error using ASp.net health monitoring

Tags: c#, asp.net, health-monitoring

I am using asp.net Health monitoring system to log errors with windows event viewer. The errors(unhandled exceptions)are logging as Warning. I want to change the level of log as error when its throwing exceptions from asp.net web applications. I want to log unhandled exceptions in windows viewer under 'error' level, but with the settings I made, I can view the exceptions occurring in asp.net web application under 'Warning' level mode. How to change this level to error?

Comment: Can to share your settings?

Comment: <eventMappings>
     <clear/>   
     <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent,System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
    </eventMappings>
    <providers>
     <clear/>   
     <add name="EventLogProvider" type="System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider,System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </providers>

Comment: <profiles>
     <add name="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom=""/>
     <add name="Critical" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" custom=""/>
    </profiles>
<rules>
     <clear/>   
     <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" />
    </rules>

Comment: I had set elements like <eventMappings>,<profiles><providers> and <rules> and placed in <healthMonitoring enabled="true"></healthMonitoring > at web.config

Comment: No, we need you to [edit] your question and put the settings info there, please take the time to use the formatting buttons!